# Difference/which gem to choose between mysql gem and ruby-mysql gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am wondering which gem to choose for ruby Mysql connector ammong the following two:

mysql
ruby-mysql

please give your comments.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

mysql2 - it is maintained, the most used at the moment, used by default by ActiveRecord.